# Using children along with react-redux (React typesciprt)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-typescript

A componenet `VerifiedComp` renders `children` if the email is verified(a prop from redux). If the email is not verified than it displays a button. The problem that I am having is that typescript is asking for children in the Parent Component.

Here is the `CreatePage` Component which is the parent component.

```
type StateTypes = {
  history: { push: (link: string) => {} };
};

const mapStateToProps = ({ history }: StateTypes) => ({
  history,
});

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, { startCreateMovie });
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;

export const CreatePage = ({ history, startCreateMovie }: PropsFromRedux) => {
  return (
    <VerifiedComp>
      <CreateForm ... />
    </VerifiedComp>
  );
};
```

And here is the `VerifiedComp`.

```
type PropTypes = {
  children: React.ReactNode
};

type StateTypes = {
  auth: { user: { emailVerified: boolean }, providerData: {email: string} };
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: StateTypes, props: PropTypes) => ({
  email: state.auth.providerData.email,
  children: props.children,
  emailVerified: state.auth.user.emailVerified
});

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps);
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;

const VerifiedComp: React.FC<PropsFromRedux> = (props: PropsFromRedux) => {
  return props.emailVerified ? (
    <React.Fragment>{props.children}</React.Fragment>
  ) : (
    <Box>.....</Box>
  )
```

Here is the complete problem

```
Type '{ children: Element; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ email: string; emailVerified: boolean; }': email, emailVerified  TS2739

    19 | export const CreatePage = ({ history, startCreateMovie }: PropsFromRedux) => {
    20 |   return (
  > 21 |     <VerifiedComp>
       |      ^
    22 |       <MovieForm
```

Comment: The only reason that React was demanding all the props from the parent component is that I have not connected `VerifiedComp` with Redux. After connecting the `VerifiedComp` with redux, React is no longer requiring props from the `CreatePage`

Comment: As far as I know `mapStateToProps` doesn't need to handle "normal" props of the component, there is a line where you just re-map `children` to `children`. Also, you're not doing anything with `connector` in the first snippet. Maybe some lines are missing?

Comment: Generally, with function components you should probably be using the hooks instead of `connect` (see the [Redux Style guide recommending hooks](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#use-the-react-redux-hooks-api)) - that way you won't have this problem in the first place

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have made children property as mandatory

```
type PropTypes = {
children: React.ReactNode
};
```

instead make it optional as below:

```
type PropTypes = {
children?: React.ReactNode
};
```